# Copy the last Emacs message into the current buffer

Tags: emacs

Is there a function I could use to quickly copy the message in the echo area (if any) into my working buffer? Should I define the shortcut for that function with `define-key` or `global-set-key` or some other way?

Comment: Are you sure the minibuffer is what you want to copy? Which buffers to you want to act on exactly: from the minibuffer associated with the current window to the current buffer?

Comment: @Gilles correct; my use case is that I want to do a `C-c+z` (which I've bound to `show-file-name`) and then copy that content (i.e. the current file name) to my current buffer. Or that I can type in the buffer an expression like (/ 30.0 7.0), hit `C-x C-e` and copy the result to my buffer without having to copy the digits with the mouse.

Comment: So what you want then isn't the minibuffer contents. The minibuffer is where you type stuff, e.g. a file name when opening a file with `C-x C-f`. Messages from Emacs also appear in the [echo area](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Echo-Area.html#Echo-Area) but they're called messages.

Comment: @Gilles I guess you're right. I was confused because of it being the same spot. Thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function [`current-message`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Messages.html#index-current_002dmessage-3675) returns the message that is currently displayed in the [echo area](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Echo-Area.html#Echo-Area), if any. You can insert it with `(insert (current-message))`. However, anything that causes something else to occupy the echo area will cause `current-message` to return `nil`.

Messages from Emacs are archived in the `*Messages*` buffer. It would be more useful to grab the last line from there. This isn't perfectly reliable since it's possible to have a multi-line message, but that's rare: the `message` function is meant for short messages that fit in one line.

The following function inserts the last message (more precisely, the last line from the `*Messages*` buffer. With a prefix argument, it returns older messages: 1 for the latest message, 2 for the next-to-last one, etc. The argument 0 inserts `(current-message)` if any.

```
(defun last-message (&optional num)
  (or num (setq num 1))
  (if (= num 0)
      (current-message)
    (save-excursion
      (set-buffer "*Messages*")
      (save-excursion
    (forward-line (- 1 num))
    (backward-char)
    (let ((end (point)))
      (forward-line 0)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) end))))))
(defun insert-last-message (&optional num)
  (interactive "*p")
  (insert (last-message num)))
```

Bind it to a key in the normal way. For example, if you want the command available on `C-c m` at all times:

```
(global-set-key "\C-cm" 'insert-last-message)
```

There may be easier ways than invoking two custom commands to insert the file name, see the [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertFileName).

To insert the output from evaluating a Lisp snippet with `C-x C-e`, pass a prefix argument: `C-u C-x C-e`.

Comment: Good but would be nice if it handled multi-line messages.

Comment: I multi-line messages would be great, but I think that it would be even cooler to be able to cycle among the previous messages!

Comment: You could also change the function to push the last few lines of the messages buffer to a list and present it with completing-read (optionally, only do the completing-read when prefixed with a universal argument).